# Authenticating with FlickrKit for iOS

Tags: ios, oauth, flickr

I am using FlickrKit to attempt to login to my Flickr account for iOS (iPhone 5 simulator).

A) I specified the following for [[FlickrKit sharedFlickrKit] initializeWithAPIKey:]
- Flickr Key
- Flickr Secret

B) Then I called [[FlickrKit sharedFlickrKit] beginAuthWithCallbackURL:]
- where the callback URL is @"MyTestApp://auth".
- "MyTestApp" is defined under URL Types -> Item 0 -> URL Schemes -> Item 0.

C) Unfortunately after the logging in process, I get this error when I try to login using FlickrKit for iOS.

> "An external application has asked to link to your Flickr account, but
>   failed to include all the necessary information. Specifically:"

(then I see a black bar, so I have no idea what the specific error is).

See screenshot below:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do i need to specify "URL Identifier"?

Comment: I'm facing the exactly same issue on Android, did you figure out the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Are you having to press the "OK, I'LL AUTHORIZE IT" button twice, with this black bar appearing the second time?

I believe what is happening is that you select the "authorize" button, which then sends the callback to your app, but when you select that button again Flickr thinks you are trying to use a duplicate auth token and wont allow it.

As a quick check, implement this method in your app delegate: 
`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

Then throw an NSLog in there to see what the url is that is being passed.  You'll probably get the data you were looking for.

I ran into this problem earlier today and was incredibly frustrated by it.

Comment: Thank you! I have added my 2 cents just in case for the next guy!

Answer (score 0):

So for the latest version of swift I had to do the following:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    if (url.host == "oauth-callback") {
        OAuth1Swift.handleOpenURL(url)
    }
    return true
}
```

Also my plist needed the following:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>my.bundle.id</string>
            <string>oauth-swift</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

But that is because I was using the following library: https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift

Answer (score 0):

This is coming over a year late. I was able to make it work by making sure the all the `info.plist` was well configured (with the right schemes. The previous dev removed it. But, it worked fine then.) and also, I `override` a function in my `AppDelegate` class. `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool` and did this

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print("DictionaryScheme: ", url.scheme!)
    if url.scheme == "schemename" {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "UserAuthCallbackNotification"), object: url)
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```